# Two 2D objects in Unity aren't colliding together

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, rigidbody

In Unity 5, I have a player shooting a projectile in aim to hit a boss, and inflict damage upon contact with the projectile. Though for some reason, the projectile and boss aren't colliding with each other.

I've done the following;

- Made sure that both the projectile and boss have a BoxCollider 2D and Rigidbody 2D
- Made sure that they're on the same Z-Index and on the same layer
- Tried to Debug.Log() if there's any collision (there isn't)
- Made sure I'm using OnCollisionEnter2D on the boss' health script
- Compared the syntax I use with another collision (where the player collides with an object and dies - this works perfectly fine).

However, none of these seem to be working.
This is the boss' health script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll)
{
    Debug.Log("COLLIDED");
    bosshealth -= 1;
}
```

Here is the projectile prefab:
[image: projectile prefab]
And the boss prefab:
[image: boss prefab]

Does anyone have a clue as to why they're not colliding? the projectile just glides over the boss

**EDIT:** I found a temporary fix! Disabling the Kinematics of the boss allows for both objects to collide, and successfully display a debug message!
Just a problem though; I don't want the boss to freely float around in space. I use the kinematic to ensure it stays put at all times until told to by scripts.

Is there a way to get around not having to disable the kinematics?

EDIT 2: Then again, I am removing the projectiles on impact anyway, so the actual boss doesn't move, but that seems dirty :/

Comment: Found a temporary solution - see edit.

Comment: [See the Collision Action Matrix on this page from the Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html): two kinematic bodies colliding does not call collision event functions. However, if you change your bullets so IsTrigger == true, then OnTriggerEnter2D *will* be called.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess it makes sense. I've set the projectile as a non-kinematic now, and I'll work it from there

Comment: Feel free to add an Answer with the fix you've found, so others can use it for reference. After a delay, you'll be able to mark your own answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory for enlightening me on this.

It turns out that you can't collide objects that both have "Is Kinematic" enabled. To get around this personally, I just unchecked "Is Kinematic" from the projectile and set it's gravity to 0, so it doesn't fly down.